# Vim: Remap Ctrl-W in insert mode to behave as it does in normal mode

Tags: vim

I would like Ctrl-W to allow me to switch windows even when I am in insert mode.  How can I make this change?

My motivation is to not need to press escape before shifting windows.

Comment: So you want to move away from one window while you are in insert mode in _that_ window. What mode do you want to be in when you move to the new window? What mode do you want to be in when you move back to the old window? And, more in general, why are you seeking this? Just to save pressing Escape before window-switching?

Comment: By the way, you might want to give a look at [this plugin of mine](https://github.com/Aster89/WinZoZ).

Comment: I added a comment to clarify that my motivation is to not need to hit escape before switching windows.  I am happy not to modify the mode of the buffer I am leaving or entering, but I suppose making sure both source and destination are in normal mode after this operation would probably be safest.

Comment: Which basically means you want C-W in insert mode to trigger Escape followed by C-W, right?

Comment: I've deleted my answer. `inoremap <C-W> <Esc>:execute "normal \<lt>C-W>\<lt>C-W>"<CR>` is for mapping `<C-W>` in insert mode to `<C-W><C-W>` in normal mode. Which is not what you want. But you might start from there. Given your repo, I guess you can see my deleted answer yourself.

Comment: @Enlico Nice plugin, easy to install:)

Comment: @yolenoyer, thank you very much of the star! :D In case you're trying it out, please, don't hesitate to give suggestions if you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `<c-w><c-j>` (as an example), you can do:

```
inoremap <c-w><c-j> <esc><c-w><c-j>gi
```

Then you can repeat this kind of mapping for every command you use:

```
inoremap <c-w><c-k> <esc><c-w><c-k>gi
inoremap <c-w><c-w> <esc><c-w><c-w>gi
inoremap <c-w>+ <esc><c-w>+gi
inoremap <c-w>- <esc><c-w>-gi
...
```

If you choose this simple solution, then you can finally add this mapping to inhibit the native `<c-w>` key (= delete the last word):

```
inoremap <c-w> <nop>
```

More "smart" solutions could be written, but they would imply a bit more code.

*Note 1*: as noted in the comments, the mappings to choose depend on which mode you want to reach after the keystroke: the suffix `gi` in the commands above means that you want to go back to insert mode in the new window; but you can remove this suffix if you want to be in normal mode.

*Note 2*: the suffix `gi` could be simply `i`, depending on the case : see `:h i` and `:h gi`