# Can I allow inline-block elements to split across lines?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, text-width

I'd like to have links zoom in when the mouse hovers on them, I've tried with `transform` unsuccessfully, but then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29667918/5825294), which looked promising.

However, making an inline element an `inline-block` also seems to prevent it from being split across several lines, as shown in the snippet below, which can create very unpleasant results for short `width` of the enclosing box.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 20em;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.01);
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Today, <a href="https://github.com/Aster89/WinZoZ">my
  Vim plugin for easy window navigation</a>, which I named
<a href="https://nonciclopedia.org/wiki/Windows">WinZoZ</a>,
has got its first star! Given <a
  href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69007954/vim-remap-ctrl-w-in-insert-mode-to-behave-as-it-does-in-normal-mode#comment121984179_69007954">this
  comment on StackOverflow</a>, the star is from the user <a
  href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/3271687/yolenoyer">@yolenoyer</a>.
</p>
</div>
```

On the other hand, in this specific example above I see that the first link is so long that it *does* split across lines, so it looks like `inline-block` elements *can indeed* do that. How can allow it when they are shorter than the text width?

Answer (score 0):

The **animation** missing is due to the original link (a tag) element not having the `transition:` property defined. Per the [positioning documentation here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) it seems only `inline-block` is suitable for flowing text and that fails to show wrapped text, even with wrap: break-word; present. The `inline-flex`, `inline-grid` don't work either since they are both ***block*** display types.

One solution would be to break the text lines at certain points and setting different `<br>` elements to show at different @media widths for certain page widths/devices. However the `inline-block` elements cannot wrap like normal text, so the breaks just end up making it a 2-line block in the middle of the text.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* text-align: justify; */
  width: 20em;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /* new */
  transition: transform .15s; /* Animations: "transform" on a-tag must be present */
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.01); /* then we transform the transition here */
  -ms-transform: scale(1.01); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.01); /* Safari 3-8 */

}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Today, <a href="https://github.com/Aster89/WinZoZ">my
  Vim plugin for easy window navigation</a>, which I named
<a href="https://nonciclopedia.org/wiki/Windows">WinZoZ</a>,
has got its first star! Given <a
  href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69007954/vim-remap-ctrl-w-in-insert-mode-to-behave-as-it-does-in-normal-mode#comment121984179_69007954">this
  comment on StackOverflow</a>, the star is from the user <a
  href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/3271687/yolenoyer">@yolenoyer</a>.
</p>
</div>
```

#### Some JS scripting

A breaking up of the line into blocks in a `ul` list with the li items being inline-block themselves could be a solution. A function to run at DOM load on each desired div's contents could do this. A loop for all `a` elements in those divs that transform each of the links into an array of words and puts the array items in a `ul -> li`. Perhaps there is a [jQuery plugin](http://httpshttps://plugins.jquery.com/) for this already.

##### Light JS example

(*not complete code*, but using `querySelectorAll`, which could be used to gather the links from a `<div>` with a class you put as the function input):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    // function to look for a-tags in a DIV with a specific class
    function linkToList(inputDivClass) { 

        // get the links inside the div with the input div class
        const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll("div." + inputDivClass + " > a");

        for (var i = allLinks.length; i < 0; i++) {
            // here we go through the links returned from the div... 
        }

        // then go through the data and see what to put where...        
    }


    // when dom is loaded we run the function that looks for the divs with the a-tags...
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", linkToList(inputDivClass) );


</script>
```